# Widevine DRM in ICS

Tags: android, drm

Can anybody tell me that widevine support is there in ICS. Is there any code available related to widevine in ICS?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Widevine support is integrated into ICS as a plug-in (the Widevine DRM Plugin) built on top of the [the Android DRM Framework](http://source.android.com/devices/drm.html), which is in Android from version 3.0 and up.

I quote from their site:

> In order to make that digital content available on Android devices and to ensure that there is at least one consistent DRM available across all devices, Google provides Widevine DRM for free on compatible Android devices. On Android 3.0 and higher platforms, the Widevine DRM plugin is integrated with the Android DRM framework and uses hardware-backed protection to secure movie content and user credentials.

You can find more information about the Android DRM framework [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/drm/package-summary.html).

Answer (score 0):

See the possible problems you can have using the built-in Widevine support: [Android: DrmManager server died](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18104050/android-drmmanager-server-died/18312568#18312568)